# how to download a file from file_get_contents?

Tags: php, download, rename, file-get-contents

I want to get a file via file_get_contents to copy and rename it and then trigger the download. In other words, a user click a link to a controller, the controller does the business and then return the new file to download.

All fine, the only thing I can't do till now is rename and force donwload of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the headers and echo out the file:

```
// Download the file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.csv"');
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($outputName));
echo (file_get_contents($outputName));
unlink($outputName);
```

Comment: +1 to @deceze comment , readfile will not use memory if the output buffering is disabled.

Comment: ok thank you. Is there a generic Content-Type header I can use, instead of targeting specific extensions?

Comment: @Stratboy, it depends what file type you're downloading. There are hundreds of mimetypes

Comment: I did a small research in the meantime: probably simply 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' is just good. I'll try.

Comment: Or you could use $http_response_header and match the source's Content-Type to pass it automatically.

Comment: Thank you @NaeiKinDus, [this is the doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)